# Caesar Cipher Shift Letters Issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, encryption, caesar-cipher, codesandbox

I was trying to program a caesar cipher using the technique of converting letter by letter with an ASCII Converter then shift the numbers and convert them again in text but it works only if the letters don't go over the z with the shift.

```
const checkPunctuation = (text) => {
  return /[.,#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g.test(text);
};

const ASCIIConverter = (text) => {
  return text.split("").map((char) => {
    return checkPunctuation(char) ? char : char.charCodeAt();
  });
};

const caesarCipher = (text, shift) => {
  return ASCIIConverter(text)
    .map((code) => (code + shift) % 26)
    .map((charCode) => String.fromCharCode(charCode))
    .join("");
};
```

```
console.log(caesarCipher("pizza!", 2));
```

Expected: wpggh!

Received:   (*Box Characters with a mark*)

Comment: Why would you expect w from p in a +2 shift? or p from i? Personally, I'd scrap all the unnecessary derived array methods and stick with a simple loop to rotate each letter in its ascii range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- There are thousands of characters that are not letters and are not in your punctuation regex. It is better to do a check for *letters*: if it is not a character from the English alphabet, then leave it unaltered.
- `return checkPunctuation(char) ? char : char.charCodeAt()` is a bad idea: this means that the mapping is to a mixed type: either string (the original character) or a number (it's code point). This affects the further processing of these values. See next point
- `.map((code) => (code + shift) % 26)` expects `code` to be a number, but it can also be a character (punctuation, see previous point), and then `+ shift` will perform string concatenation and `% 26` will produce `NaN` in that case. This obviously is not what is intended.
- `.map((code) => (code + shift) % 26)` results in numbers between 0 and 25 (and `NaN`), which are not the ASCII codes of letters but of control characters.
- `.map((charCode) => String.fromCharCode(charCode))` will convert control codes (and `NaN`) to their character representations, which are those boxes you see. You need to add the ASCII code of the letter 'a' back to it before converting to a string.
- The example call is wrong. A shift of 2 would not give "wpggh!" as result. For that you would need to use a shift of 7 (as "w" occurs 7 letters after the letter "p" in the alphabet).

Here is the proposed correction:

```js
const convertRange = (text, regex, a, shift) =>
  text.replace(regex, letter => 
    String.fromCharCode(
      (letter.charCodeAt() - a.charCodeAt() + shift) % 26 + a.charCodeAt()
    )
  );

const caesarCipher = (text, shift) => {
  text = convertRange(text, /[A-Z]/g, 'A', shift); // Cypher uppercase
  return convertRange(text, /[a-z]/g, 'a', shift); // Cypher lowercase
};

console.log(caesarCipher("pizza!", 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

`charCodeAt` probably simply returns the index in ASCII. What you need is the index in the range `[0..n)`, where `n` in this case is 26. Same problem with `fromCharCode` of course, which receives the tiny values after the `%26` is applied. Generally you can subtract / add the value of `A` or `a` to get the values into the correct range.

Generally I propose to add methods to convert the ASCII index into the index of the alphabet and back again. Those can be tested separately. The problem with this highly concise code is that it is horrid to debug; too much happens when mapping the values in the "stream".

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the code is decreasing values incorrectly.
For example, the char code of A is 65 but becomes 20.
If capitalization doesn't matter, you could use

`String.fromCharCode((charCode - 65)%26 + 65)`

This puts values in the correct range for upper-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Caesar's Cypher function that will rotate only the ASCII characters [A-Z] and [a-z]:

```js
function cc(str,n){
 return str.split("").map(c=>{
  let a=c.charCodeAt(0)-1
  if (a>63&&a<90||a>95&&a<122)
   a=(a%32+n)%26+64+(a>95?32:0)
  return String.fromCharCode(a+1);
 }).join("");
}

console.log(cc("Most fabulous - our Pizzas!",7));
```